# I want to hide a div based on user's select

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm writing a form and I'd like to display the payment method for CC or payPal by displaying the relevant `<div>`

My JS function :

```
function myFunction() { 
    if (payment.value == "Credit Card")
    {
        document.getElementById("PP").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    if (payment.value == "PayPal") {
      document.getElementById("CC").style.display= "hidden";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="payment" id="payment" select = "selected" onChange="myFunction()">
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Suggestions?

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How specifically is it failing?  When you debug this, are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  Where does the expected behavior fail when you step through in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right value for css properties.

`display` can be "none","block", "" (nothing)

`visibility` can be "hidden", "visible"

you also need to restore the visibility of the other element.

```
function myFunction(payment) { 

    if (payment.value == "Credit Card")
    {
        document.getElementById("PP").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("CC").style.display= "block";
    }
    if (payment.value == "PayPal") {
      document.getElementById("CC").style.display= "none";
      document.getElementById("PP").style.display= "block";
    }
}
```

And the select box should be:

```
<select ... onchange="myFunction(this.value);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
function myFunction() { 
 var payment =document.getElementById("payment");
if (payment.value == "Credit Card")
{
    document.getElementById("PP").style.display = "none";
}
if (payment.value == "PayPal") {
  document.getElementById("CC").style.display= "none";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct some stuff.

HTML

```
<select name="payment" id="payment" select ="selected" onChange="myFunction()">
    <option value="cred_car">Credit Card</option>
    <option value="paypal">PayPal</option>
</select>

    <div id="PP">PP</div>
    <div id="CC">CC</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() { 
    //alert (payment.value);
    if (payment.value == "cred_car")
    {
        document.getElementById("CC").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("PP").style.display = "block";
    }
    if (payment.value == "paypal") {
      document.getElementById("PP").style.display= "none";
      document.getElementById("CC").style.display= "block";
    }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pefcf508/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few ways you can improve this to make it work.

- Pass in "this" reference when calling myFunction to make it easier to get your selection
- Be sure to hide the non-selected values and show the selected value so that you don't just hide values.
- Initially call the myFunction to set the visibility based on the default selection

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/04keaLfr/

Here is the HTML:

```
<select name="payment" id="payment" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
    <option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
</select>
<div id="PP">Paypal selected</div>
<div id="CC">Credit Card selected</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function myFunction(el) {
    var selected = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('CC').style.display = (selected == 'Credit Card' ? 'inline' : 'none');
    document.getElementById('PP').style.display = (selected == 'PayPal' ? 'inline' : 'none');
}
myFunction(document.getElementById('payment'));
```